# Spring cacheable annotation with multiple key

Tags: spring, spring-cache

I have 2 ways to lookup a customer record (code below), customerGuid and customerId are 2 different fields in Customer object.

Suppose that i lookup customer by customerId once, is there a way for me to lookup customer by guid directly from cache without querying backend, Assuming both the methods return type is Customer.

```
public class CustomerLookup {
    @Cacheable("customerCache")
    public Customer getCustomerByGuid(final String customerGuid) {
        // some implementation here...
    }

    @Cacheable("customerCache")
    public Customer getCustomerByCustId(final String customerId) {
        // some implementation here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a 2nd parameter to one method which will only serve as cache key. Example use `customerId` as key and proceed like this:

```
@Service
public class CustomerLookup {
   @Autowired
   @Lazy
   private CustomerLookup self;

   @CachePut("customerCache", key="#customerId")
   public Customer getCustomerByGuid(final String customerGuid, String customerId) {
     Customer customer = self.getCustomerByCustId(final String customerId);
     //......
   }
}
```

Note the self-injection of `CustomerLookup` if you don't do that the cache won't work when you call the `getCustomerByCustId(final String customerId)` method in `getCustomerByGuid`. Also note the `@CachePut` instead of `@Cacheable` on `getCustomerByGuid`, with this you are sure that this method will be called everytime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however in mycase the caller of getCustomerByGuid() mayn't always know or have customerId. Thats one of the reason why there are 2 lookup methods.